# parse data into header-html library pdfkit

Tags: python, header, pdfkit

I'm using the pdfKit library in python, and I set an html header with url but I want to parse some values into this header. The API pdfkit is based in wkhtmltopdf API, taking a look in the last one:

```
   `replace <name> <value>` - > Replace [name] with value in header and footer (repeatable)
```

And the API pdfkit pattern is:

```
options = {
'page-size': 'Letter',
'margin-top': '0.75in',
'margin-right': '0.75in',
'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
'margin-left': '0.75in',
'encoding': "UTF-8",
'no-outline': None
```

}

but I can't find the way to parse the option "replace" and I try a lot of variants.

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty late response but for anyone looking for an answer, PDFkit takes an option dict `{ "option_name": "value" }` and adds it to the command:

```
wkhtmltopdf ... --option_name value
```

so in this case where you want `-replace <name> <value>`
you could give a dictionary with the option value being the two values joined by a space, e.g.

```
{ 
    "replace": "%s %s" % (name, value)
}
```